# There in an ambiguity in this ERD scenario

Tags: database, erd

> Consider the N&N database application regarding different publishers. The publishers publish books written by various authors. The books can be published only after signing contract with the authors. The authors may sign contact with different publishers and a publisher may sign contract with different author. A publisher may publish more than one books whereas no two publishers can publish same book written by same author. Each contract between publisher and author contains contract start date, end date and contract cancellation penalty. A person will be considered as an author if he writes at least one book and each book is written by at least one author. N&N keeps publisher name, address and max two phone numbers (personal, office) as record of publishers. For authors the organization keeps their identification number F_Name, L_Name, P_NO , DOB to calculate the age, subject areas, Address in which HNO, Street NO, Postal Code is kept as record. There may be more than one authors writing books on same subject area and an author may write books of different subject areas. The book is identified by ISBN. It has title, number of pages, the year of publication and category. There may be more than one books belonging to same category but one book must belong to at-max one category.

In this scenario would there be a separate entity for category? 
and 
Would there be a tertiary relation between author publisher and contract?

Comment: Is a category a subject area?

Comment: no both are different i suppose that's one of the ambiguous parts of this problem.

Comment: I guess subject area is covered in by the attb of category 
The book is identified by ISBN. It has title, number of pages, the year of publication and category.
But then this line knocks me off as they represent category as a separate entity
There may be more than one books belonging to same category but one book must belong to at-max one category.

Comment: This question is so confusing that each paradigm seems right, its just playing with my head now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Categories**

Distinctions between entities, relationships, properties and associative entities are essentially arbitrary.

The only category relationship is "book B ... and has category C". A book participates 0-or-1 times. We are not told whether there are categories with no books, ie whether a category must participate. A category can participate many times.

If the relationship is 0-or-1 to 1-or-more then all categories participate. So if you want to know all the categories then they are the categories in the relationship. So a category can be a property of book (or be an entity). Otherwise (the relationship is 0-or-1 to 0-or-more) we need to know the categories that don't participate. If the extant categories never change then they can be 1:1 with values of a domain. So a category can be a property of book (or can be an entity). Otherwise categories come and go so they need to be entities. Considering that it isn't gone into whether categories come and go or whether one must be associated with a book, the simplest case is a domain of categories, so a category property/attribute is adequate.

**Author-publisher-contract**

There are *many* ternary relationships on these three entity types. What you want to know is whether there should be a *base* one.

We know about "author A and publisher P signed a contract". But it is not clear but whether an author and a publisher can sign more that one contract. Eg it is not clear whether each book gets a contract.

If there can only be one contract then there is no need for a base relation "author A and publisher P signed contract C". Otherwise (there can be more than one contract) you need a ternary relationship. Considering that it isn't gone into, the simplest answer is not to have one.

**On requirements**

It isn't enough to just know all relevant relationships and things to draw an ERD. We need to know all base relationships & full cardinalities for when a thing is treated as an entity. Then per limitations we may be able to downgrade an entity to a property or relationship. You should ask for the requirements to be filled in.

Comment: So to cut it down your'e saying that 
Contract isn't in a tertiary relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Would there be a separate entity for the category?**

---

Ref: The book is identified by ISBN. It has title, number of pages, the year of publication and category.
*Ans: This line shows that the category is a single-valued attribute of Book*

AND

Ref: There may be more than one books belonging to same category but one book must belong to at max one category.

*Ans: This line shows that Different books may have same category attribute but one book cannot have multiple categories and this attribute must be NOT-NULL*

So, Category will be Attribute of Book.

---

2. **Would there be a tertiary relation between author, publisher and contract?**

---

Ref: The books can be published only after signing the contract with the authors.

*Ans: This line shows that there should be a ternary relationship*.
PUBLISHER(s) sign CONTACT with AUTHOR(s) or vice verse.

Comment: The requirements do not say that whether there are categories other than those associated with books that can come and go; if so, they are entities. The requirements do not say whether there is more than one contract per author & publisher; if not, there does not need to be a ternary relationship.

Comment: It is clearly stated in the given Problem "Book has the year of publication and category". Note that the word category is singular. If there may be more than one categories than it should be plural. So, its a single-valued attribute. Moreover, if Category would be an entity it must have some  properties (attributes).
Also it is stated "The authors may sign contact with different publishers and a publisher may sign contract with different author"
which shows author may sign contracts with different publishers. So there will be a Ternary relation

Comment: Nothing in your comment contradicts my comment. Eg Knowing author:publisher is many:many doesn't tell you whether an author & publisher can have more than one contract; only if they can have more than one is there a ternary relationship. See my answer.

Comment: They have more than one in the given context that's why it would be a ternary brother

Comment: No sentence in the requirements says that there is more than one contract between a given author & given publisher.

Comment: So putting it to a conclusion @philipxy you are saying not to have a tertiary relationship am i correct and Category would be an attribute/property not an entity.

Comment: @SyedTayyabAbbas The requirements are unclear. Either you say it can't be decided, or design for a property when in doubt, or design for an entity when in doubt, or design some interpretation you picked. As a school assignment, ask for which to do, or ask for full info, or just give your interpretation(s). For simplest, Category as property, Contracts as relationship or Contract as associative entity. For worst case, Category as entity & Contract as entity with ternary relationship. Maybe you just feel there should be a contract entity, even when 1:1 with author-publisher pairs.